# Lua whitelist to sanitize and allow clean URL string only

Tags: lua

So I am trying to come up with a method that will allow clean URL's only and make the string empty if it contains any character(s) it should not.

Whitelist of Characters i want the url to accept only

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 _ - . /
```

Lua Code Example :

```
local bar = "com/url/index.php/html/path/stuff.html.html123/..lol"
bar = bar:gsub("%.html.*$","")
bar = bar:gsub("%/$","")
bar = bar:gsub("%.$","")
print(bar)
--TODO: if characters not in whitelist then make bar empty
bar = ""
```

Clean output:

```
com/url/index.php/html/path/stuff
```

Dirty output: (This is what I want to get rid of because characters not whitelisted or multiple unnecessary slashes)

```
com/url///////index.php/html//////path///////stuff

com/url///////+index.php/=html//////path///////stuff@[
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean. Try this.

```
if bar:gsub("[A-Za-z0-9_%-%./]","")=="" then
    -- bar is ok
else
    bar=""
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer it works the only problem left is do you know how i can fix the multiple slashes issue as shown above

Comment: Why waste memory allocating a new string when there's `string.find()`?